# Can't send mail trough online host server

Tags: php, email, hosting

When I send mail trough my local set-up server (http://bftanker.l) the email works perfectly and gets to the correct mailclient (xxx@bftanker.com). When I upload my website to their hosting platform I always get the same "Client timed out" error.

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM: ...
```

Any suggestions? Is this a checkbox somewhere on the hostingplatform or do I have a code error?

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'smtp.bftanker.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '2525';

$config['smtp_user']    = 'xxxx@bftanker.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'xxxxxx';
$config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']    = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
$config['validation'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'Warre Buysse');
$this->email->to('xxxxx@bftanker.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test Local');
$this->email->message('Testing the email.');  
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I am using the Codeigniter framework.
Feel free to test the form and see the print_debugger at http://www.bftanker.com

Comment: Make sure that your host allows email from PHP.

Comment: This is a host specific issue for sure.

Comment: Is there a possibility to check that in some way? And to edit that?

Comment: You have to contact your provider for specific instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line:
    $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'Warre Buysse');
if it starts to work, means that your host blocks emails, which "from" field is different than smtp user.

Comment: hm.. maybe try connect to smtp by telnet. Then connect by ssh to their server (if they have ssh) and from there also check smtp. Maybe something with configuration? Below link to desc. how to use telnet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx